# How to convert a USB device button to simulate keyboard button in C#?

Tags: c#, events, usb

I've a digital mike with buttons like play,pause,stop. I can "listen" the events on these buttons by using it's SDK. But I want to use these buttons on a web page.

In my webpage, I can "listen" the multimedia keyboard keys like play,pause, and stop. So I want to map the mike buttons so that pressing the button actually creates an event created by corresponding key on the keyboard.

For example, If I press "pause" button on my USB mike, the keyboard "pause button" event should be triggered. How can I achieve this? and will I have to create a windows service for this?

Comment: If it is a HID input/keyboard, it should work already.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into the [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Or alternatively the older and simpler [`keybd_event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx).

While MS recommends using `SendInput`, I'd probably use `keybd_event` because the native interop for it looks a lot easier. To me it looks like the main advantage of `SendInput` is that it supports multiple inputs within a single call. But you don't need that anyways.

Answer (score 0):

read up on windows hooks.They can be used to simulate keyboard events etc.  Most of the code is in c++ but I am sure you can find libraries that provider wrappers for these functions in C#

Comment: There is a lot of complexity surrounding hooks so I can't explain how exactly to solve your problem but these links should be a good starting point and good luck!

Comment: If you have additional information to your answer, please add them to the answer body (using the `edit` link) instead of adding comments. If you edit in the comments now into the body, you can delete the comments through the crossed circle icon that appears next to your own comments when hovering the comment with the mouse.

Comment: P.S you will have to intercept the event for your USB button and call the handlers for the e.g "pause" button.. At-least this is  what I was investigating before just simply using AutohotKey which solved my particular problem.